# GlassFish 4.1 in Eclipse errors java.io.FileNotFoundException: null/config/domain.xml (file or directory does not exist)

Tags: java, eclipse, glassfish, glassfish-4

I'm trying to start glassfish from eclipse luna but I have this error

```
Unable to start server due following issues:
java.io.FileNotFoundException: null/config/domain.xml (file or directory does not exist)
```

Glassfish works correctly if I start it with command

```
sudo ./asadmin start-domain domain1
```

from the shell.

How can I achieve the same result without going always through the terminal?

Comment: Looks like your Glassfish instance is not correctly setup in Eclipse. What did you do to set it up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reinstall:

- Eclipse Luna

- GlassFish 4

Delete all old file. Then reinstall Eclipse-GlassFish connector (because start up GlassFish manually still working.)

Answer (score 9):

I faced exactly this problem today. The domain path is missing in GlassFish configuration. This can happen when you add GlassFish 4.x server  in all hassle without completing the entire *Add Server* wizard. The domain path is set during 3rd step which would be skipped when you finish the wizard already during 1st or 2nd step.

You can put it back in server's properties. Rightclick GlassFish entry in *Servers* view, choose *Properties*, open *GlassFish* and set the *Domain path* accordingly (it would be blank when you faced this problem).

[image]

No need to reinstall the whole IDE and server as suggested in other answer. That's way too drastic.